# Elastic Beanstalk: can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This error message is a well known error message. (see https://bundler.io/blog/2019/01/04/an-update-on-the-bundler-2-release.html for example.) Although I'm getting it with a new Elastic Beanstalk application with Ruby 2.6.1, and bundler 2.0.1. The error is:

```
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>' (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

I've tried putting the following file: `01_install_bundler.config` in the `.ebextensions` folder:

```
container_commands:
  01_install_bundler:
    command: "gem install bundler —-version 2.0.1"
```

Although this never gets run because if I look at the above error, I can see that it is happening during this point in the deploy process:

```
.../AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/10_bundle_install.sh] : Activity failed.
```

(i.e. during the `bundle install` command of an AppDeployPreHook script). See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html for reference of PlatformHooks.

I'm pretty sure that if I can ensure that the version of bundler being used is at least version 2.0.0, then there won't be a problem. Although I don't know how I can specify that easily. At the moment I'm ssh'ing to the server to `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/` to edit and fiddle with the scripts. Although I obviously need an automated, repeatable way of doing it.

It's frustrating that ruby 2.6.1 isn't choosing bundler version 2.0.0 by default. Any ideas?

==============================

Update:

If I edit the file `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh`

```
if [ -f Gemfile ]; then
  echo "running 'bundle install' with Gemfile:"
  cat Gemfile

  +++ gem install bundler +++
  if [ -d $EB_APP_STAGING_DIR/vendor/cache ]; then
    bundle install --local
  else
    bundle install
  fi
else
  echo "no Gemfile found! Skipping bundle install stage!"
fi
```

and add the `gem install bundler` (without the pluses), then this fixes the problem because it installs the latest bundler, which is 2.0.1. For those who want to know the hack, the commands were:

`eb ssh`

`sudo -i`

`cd /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre`

`vim 10_bundle_install.sh`

The problem with this solution is that it feels like a bit of a hack because it doesn't use `.ebextensions`. Is there a more proper way of fixing this?

Comment: Tried the `10_bundle_install.sh1` hack and had EB complain that I shouldn't try to install Bundler as root.

Comment: @NBarnes, that might be because when you're running `eb deploy` you're probably connecting with the aws_access_key and aws_secret_access_key of your root AWS account. AWS recommends that you use Identity Access Management (IAM) for this purpose. It's not too hard to set up. Under IAM -> Users, you'll just need to create a user with these permissions: `AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess` and `ElasticLoadBalancingFullAccess`. Then create access keys for that user and run `eb deploy` with that profile instead.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I created a new User using IAM and gave them those two permissions.  I am still getting the error about running Bundler as root, however.  I did reset the credentials in the AWS CLI; `cat ~/.aws/config` shows the access keys for the non-root user.

EDIT: Is the problem perhaps that in the extension file snippet below you have `owner` set to `root`?

Comment: I not sure @NBarnes. The `owner` of `root` below is the file owner. Whereas it sounds like your error is talking about the user being `root` while executing that file, not that the file itself is owned by `root`. If you google search "install Bundler as root" there are a few possible explanations. And perhaps your AWS environment is different to mine? I'm running `Passenger with Ruby 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.1`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So here's the programmatic solution to the above problem. Create the below file under `.ebextensions/gem_install_bundler.config`:

```
files:
  # Runs before `./10_bundle_install.sh`:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/09_gem_install_bundler.sh" :
    mode: "000775"
    owner: root
    group: users
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash

      EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir)
      EB_SCRIPT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir)
      # Source the application's ruby, i.e. 2.6. Otherwise it will be 2.3, which will give this error: `bundler requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0` 
      . $EB_SCRIPT_DIR/use-app-ruby.sh

      cd $EB_APP_STAGING_DIR
      echo "Installing compatible bundler"
      gem install bundler -v 2.0.1
```

Then when you next `eb deploy`, the bundler will have been updated to version 2.0.1, and you won't get the above error again.

More information in the docs here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html

and here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-files

Last note: Ensure that you either commit these changes before running `eb deploy`, or stage them and run `eb deploy --staged`. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cli-git.html. I learned this the hard way!

Comment: i added this file, but still got the same error, the strange thing is that i do not get the echo, but inside the archive there is the `.ebextensions/gem_install_bundler.config` file in the root level -- is there something else that I have to do? I am using Ruby 2.6.3

Comment: If you don't get the `echo` then it's not executing at all. Try moving the `echo` as the first statement to be executed, in case your above commands are failing.

Comment: I had to add `gem update --system` at the end of the file and it fixed the problem :)

Comment: This worked for me. In my particular case I had to set the Bundler version to 2.0.2 instead of 2.0.1.

Comment: "Custom platform hooks are a legacy feature that exists on Amazon Linux AMI platforms. On Amazon Linux 2 platforms, custom platform hooks in the /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/ folder are entirely discontinued." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that can be used on the new Amazon Linux 2 platform versions as the old `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/` folders are entirely discontinued. It parses the bundler version out of the Gemfile.lock

This script would go into `.platform/hooks/prebuild/01_install_app_bundler.sh` and it needs to be marked as executable or it will fail with a permissions issue (`chmod +x 01_install_app_bundler.sh`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Load environment data
EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config platformconfig -k AppStagingDir)
EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config platformconfig -k AppUser)
EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config platformconfig -k AppDeployDir)

# Set up correct environment
export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)

BUNLDER_VER_TO_INSTALL=$(grep -A 1 "BUNDLED WITH" Gemfile.lock | tail -n1 | tr -d ' ')

echo "Installing bundler $BUNLDER_VER_TO_INSTALL"
gem install bundler -v $BUNLDER_VER_TO_INSTALL
```

I left some unused EB_ variables in there just to show how they can be determined on the updated platform.

Answer (score 1):

I only just saw this post after I had found an alternative (perhaps easier) solution: backgrading bundler to 1.17.3 (`gem unistall bundler` followed up with  `gem install bundler -v 1.17.3`)

Answer (score 0):

You need the correct version of the bundler that the lockfile was generated with. To find out that version, use the following command

```
$ cat Gemfile.lock | grep -A 1 "BUNDLED WITH"
BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3
```

Comment: Or scroll to the bottom of the lock file and see "Bundled With"